# Finding the value of constant from pdf

Tags: self-learning, density-function

Consider a random sample $X$ with pdf $ f(x)=\frac{k(p)}{x^{p}} $ for $x>1$, $p>0$ and $k(p) $ is a positive constant. Find set of possible values of $p$ for which variance is finite and fourth moment doesn't exist.

On direct solving, using the fact that integral over the entire range should be equal to 1, I found that if $0<p<1$ then the value of integrand becomes infinity. Does this mean that $p>1$?. How do I go about this problem further?

Comment: Would you please type the problem rather than embedding it as an image?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Bbb E X^n=\int_1^\infty k(p)x^{n-p}dx=\frac{k(p)}{k(p-n)}$ provided $p>n+1$ for convergence, otherwise this expectation is infinite. So when is the mean $\mu:=\Bbb EX$ finite? When does the variance $\sigma^2:=\Bbb E X^2-\mu^2$ exist? What about the kurtosis $\sigma^{-4}\Bbb E(X-\mu)^4$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that $k(p)$ is a positive constant. I've edited the question.

Comment: Is the answer $p>4$?

Comment: @user46697 Note the $+1$ in my inequality.

Comment: $n$ can only be 3 since it's given in the question that fourth moment doesn't exist. hence $p>4$.